# javascript str.replace color the word preceding a string

Tags: javascript, regex

In a csv.file a column 'col2' row contains a string:

```
"unserer {m}, unsere {p} and {f}, unseres {n}"
```

it is appended dynamically

```
d3.select("#element").html(d.col2)
```

based on the content of {m|f|n} I would like to change the background color of the text.

I am looking with a regex statement like this:

```
/.*(\w+)\s\{f\}.*/
```

where I want to replace the \w+ with

```
'<span style=background-color:red|yellow|green;>$1</span>
```

and I need this for three use case being {m}, {f}, {n}, which each are supposed to have their own  text color. So

```
 d3.select("#sentence").html(d.col2).html(function(d) {
   if ( this.match("{m}"){ 
        this.replace(/.*(\w+)\s\{m\}/gi, "<span  style=color:red;>" + $1"</span>");
 } if ( this.match("{f}") {
       this.replace(/.*(\w+)\s\{f\}/gi, "<span style=color:yellow;>" + $1"</span>");
 } else {
 this.replace(/.*(\w+)\s\{n\}/gi, "<span style=color:green;>" + $1"</span>");
 }
 };)
```

This code is rather pseudocode of what I would like to do; it is not working and I am not sure that it can be done this way.

Comment: Can you show us the expected final output from your example string?

Comment: Can you create an example fiddle or plunker of your code?  I attempted to answer your last question but am very confused as to how you are data-binding..

Comment: "unserer {m}, unsere {f}, unseres {n}"  is also the final output, but ist should have 'unserer' in red, 'unsere' in yellow and 'unseres' in green.

Comment: @Mark the data binding is o.k. The element "#sentence" is set on click: click = function(d) { d3.select("#sentence").html(d.col2) };  d.col2 is part of data which is a dataset from a csv with columns col1, col2 etc. The string appears first in a tooltip: on click it is appended to the '#sentence'.

Comment: These are dictionary words that should be colored according to gender. The problem is rather to replace, or split and join the strings. If each string would contain one gender only, it would not be a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to explain the German to me - I *am* German.  ;-)

Here is my version of a RegExp, that maybe treats the genders and plurals a bit better:

```
var r=/(^|,)\s*(.*?)(?=\s+\{([fmn])\})/g;
s.replace(r,'$1<span class="$3">$2</span>');
```

For simplicity I assigned the spans the classes m,n and f.

My RegExp looks for *anything* between a valid gender tag ({m},{f} or {n}) and the start of the string or a `,` (comma) and considers that to be the string that needs coloring.

The result of this would be

```
'<span class="m">unserer</span> {m}<span class="f">unsere {p} and</span> {f}<span class="n">unseres</span> {n}'
```

The classes of course need to be given suitable colors in your CSS.

**update**

As you know, good things can always be improved, so here is a version that will not color the `{p}` tags (or anything starting with `'{'`):

```
s.replace(/(^|,)\s*([^{]+)(?=.*?\{([fmn])\})/g,'$1<span class="$3">$2</span>')
```

This will get you

```
'<span class="m">unserer </span>{m},<span class="f">unsere </span>{p} and {f},<span class="n">unser </span>{n}'
```

Comment: Impressionante. Your answer does it as intended. `d3.select("#sentence").html(d.col2.replace(/(?:^|,)\s*(.*?)(?=\s+\{([fmn])\})/g,'<span class="$2">$1</span>'));` Thank you aus Lastrup.

Comment: I edited my post a little bit, since the commas were lost otherwise. Please check it again. Best regards  back from Hanover!

Comment: Why is the `^` needed in your regex ? I guess I get it though. Absolutely cool, and very, very handy for my application.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *function* as the replacor in [**`str.replace`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and you can use a [***lookahead***](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in your *RegExp*

```
var str = "unserer {m}, unsere {p} and {f}, unseres {n}";

var d = {
        m: 'red',
        f: 'yellow',
        n: 'green'
    },
    re = /(\w+)(?=\s+\{([^}]+)\})/g;
str = str.replace(
    re,
    function ($0, $1, $2) {
        if ($2 in d)
            return '<span style="color:' + d[$2] + ';">' + $1 + '</span>';
        return $0;
    }
);
// '<span style="color:red;">unserer</span> {m}, unsere {p} <span style="color:yellow;">and</span> {f}, <span style="color:green;">unseres</span> {n}'
```

Comment: Yes, so far so good! But it gets a bit tricky when it comes to treat the 'and' between the genders or plural tags properly. Obviously OP *really* wanted the word 'unsere' to appear in yellow (although he didn't explicitly say so ...).

Comment: Thank you, Paul. I will work through it and  fit it into my code and post back here

Comment: @cars10 {m} stands for male, {f} for female: I want to emphasize the gender  with different colors. 'unserer' is 'our' - male, 'unsere' is 'our' - female in German. All words of interest are marked with {gender_here}. The '{p} and {f}' case can probably be dropped if that gets too complex..

Comment: yes, the 'and' should not be colored, I may have to  change the csv entries ( 15.000 ) to {pf} or something alike if it can't be done here